# Cannot Attach photo using paperclip on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Here is my controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @article=Article.new

end
def index
    @articles = Article.all
end
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end  
def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])


end
def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if @article.update(article_params)
redirect_to @article
else
  render 'edit'
end
end
def destroy
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.destroy

redirect_to articles_path
end
private
    def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end

end
```

Here's my form

```
<%= form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I am not able to upload the photo infact it does not show any error, but neither anything(path of image) is saved on database nor any photo is saved. I am new on rails, just trying to create a form which have features of uploading photo.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
has_attached_file :photo
validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }
end
```

I have tried almost every tutorial and also found some of the [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407013/rails-4-add-file-field-for-attachment-upload-to-existing-form-and-controller) but it seems nothing has resolved the issue. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `photo` to your strong params:

```
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :photo)
end
```

Without it the value is not passed over to the model to be validated and saved.

I am assuming you already ran the migration to add Paperclip's `photo_file_name`, `photo_file_size`, `photo_content_type`, `photo_updated_at` fields to your `articles` table.

Note: It is only necessary to include the attached file name `photo` in the strong parameters; as long as this value reaches the model Paperclip will handle the rest.

In addition, you need to disable Paperclip's spoofing validation.  It uses the OS `file` command the determine the MIME type of the file but Windows doesn't have a file command so it always fails.  You can disable the spoofing check by putting something like this in an initializer:

```
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I tried it earlier, but showed an error, so i removed that. Error shows "Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError in ArticlesController#update". I came up with that error before also. At that I added "validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }
" in my model. But I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Did you try with `photo` in the strong parameters **AND** the `validates_attachment` in the model?  You need both; strong params to pass the photo to the model, and validates_attachment because Paperclip insists you validate at least the content type or file name.

Comment: Parden me. I somehow removed that Paperclip error, that was silly one. But now as I am uploading a .jpg extension image file. It shows error in article page as "Photo has an extension that does not match its contents".